# Lucene Search Library Algorithm Used

Tags: java, algorithm, search, lucene

I have heard about library `Lucene` by apache,I have searched all over the internet to know the search algorithm used by `lucene` but I cant find anything,please tell me anyone about this.I mean that Is there any algorithm used by lucene like `Linear Search`, `Binary tree Search`....

Answer (score 2):

[Lucene](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://lucene.apache.org/core/&ei=7vRnU8SeN6Oy7AaC94HACA&usg=AFQjCNFUWH4QNE3qjb53P9oILG1p3LwpdQ&sig2=bXoZE71OpgL3cXoy6oU6aQ) is a library for [Information Retrieval (IR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval), it focuses on how to search queries (keywords) in a huge corpus, based on an index, similar to (some of the things) google do.

The most basic idea of IR is to build an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) from the corpus that maps from each word to all documents containing it.

If for example you have:

```
d1 = as good as it gets and more
d2 = the good the bad and the ugly
d3 = Is it ugly and bad? It is, and more!
```

It will build an inverted index that looks something like that:

```
as: d1, 
good: d1, d2
it: d1, d3
gets: d1
and: d1, d2, d3
...
```

Now, if you search for the word (term) 'it', the index can efficiently and easily tell you 'it' appears in d1 and in d2. This is the most basic concept of building an index and searching it.

Of course, there is much more to it and you are encouraged to learn more about these algorithms. This is in fact a huge area of study, and new research are published on daily basis. To learn more, I found Manning's [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) very helpful.